# Handle expired SQL login's passwords in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, logins, password, smo

Is it possible to change the password for a login with an expired password using *SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)* programming?

Many times during working hours I got this message from a production server.
I have a 'sa' level privilege in SQL Server.

[image: Screenshot]

#### Working Environment

1. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express
2. Windows Server 2012 R2
3. VMware,Inc. VMware virtual platform

Comment: are those password used by users? why are they changing so many times a day ? Perhaps you should use windows auth with AD and groups/roles

Comment: Basic answer: Yes you can use SMO to change a password for a SQL Login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Login.ChangePassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.login.changepassword.aspx) Method:

```
public void ChangePassword(
    string newPassword,
    bool unlock,
    bool mustChange
)
```

You can also change the password using T-SQL:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'123456'
GO
```

Maximum password age can be set:

- Open Administrative Tools / Local Security Policy (or run SECPOL.MSC).
- Go to Security Settings / Account Policies / Password Policy
- Update Maximum Password Age

It can also be set by AD and GPO.

Comment: Through TSQL i am able to change password.Even i an only able to execute TSQL through SSMS. So, i am accept as answer. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there is a better solution iff you add more information and details. It's unclear why only SSMS works and what is the real problem when you are trying to change it.

Comment: Yes exactly what i had said, only i am able to execute TSQL through 'New Query'  window in SSMS. Not able to right click to any folder of  SQL Server instance. It's Live production Server.

Comment: Perfect. TSQL is the right way to do it. You should avoid clicks on Prod.

Comment: Really you are awesome. +1 for that

Answer (score 6):

Complementing to [Julien's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130022/8783), **you can be proactive** to schedule below tsql as a job to alert you on daily basis especially on [`DaysUntilExpiration` of `LOGINPROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx) e.g. get all the logins from your database server that are going to expire in 2 days.

```
SELECT name as LoginName,
create_date as LoginCreateDate,
modify_date as LoginModifiedDate,
is_policy_checked ,
is_expiration_checked ,
-- returns the number of days until the password expires.
LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'DaysUntilExpiration') DaysUntilExpiration,
LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'PasswordLastSetTime') PasswordLastSetTime,
LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'IsExpired') IsExpired,
LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'IsMustChange') IsMustChange
From sys.sql_logins
--- optional filter 
-- where LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'DaysUntilExpiration') >= 2
```

Comment: It's a really good script for my environment.For that +1